# Send Email List c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a page with **"Folder Access"** and one `CheckBox`.

Today, in my `.cs`, for each `checkbox` checked in this **Folder Access**, I send email to the Owner of this folder.
To get this email, I create in my page a HiddenField to Email.

But, now, I have more than one Owner for each Folder. if it continues this way, I have duplicate rows.
How I can get a list to Email for each Folder?

My `.aspx`

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FolderAccess" HeaderText="Folder Access" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Access to Read" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_ChangeCheck"
                AutoPostBack="true" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="Email" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("Email") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

My `.cs`

```
public class ListRequest
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FolderAccess { get; set; }
}

public List<ListRequest> PreencheValores(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    var lista = new List<ListRequest>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var listRequest = new ListRequest();

        listRequest.Email = reader["Email"].ToString();
        listRequest.FolderAccess = reader["FolderAccess"].ToString();
        lista.Add(listRequest);
    }
    return lista;
}


public List<ListRequest> ConsultarRequest()
{
    var lstRetorno = new List<ListRequest>();
    using (objConexao = new SqlConnection(strStringConexao))
    {
        using (objCommand = new SqlCommand(strSelectPorID, objConexao))
        {
            try
            {
                objConexao.Open();
                var objDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader();
                if (objDataReader.HasRows)
                    lstRetorno = PreencheValores(objDataReader);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                objConexao.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    return lstRetorno;
}

protected void btnSend_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox check = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        HiddenField hd1 = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("Email");
        string email = hd1.Value.ToString();

        if (check.Checked == true)
        {

            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage objEmail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            objEmail.From = new MailAddress("caio.jesus@br.com", "XXX");
            objEmail.To.Add(email);
            objEmail.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;
            objEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            objEmail.Subject = "System NDRSecurity - Novas Requisições.";
            objEmail.Body = "TEST";
            objEmail.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
            objEmail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
            SmtpClient objSmtp = new SmtpClient("XXX");
            objSmtp.EnableSsl = true;
            objSmtp.Port = 25;
            objSmtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("caio.jesus@br.com", "XXX");
            objSmtp.Send(objEmail);
        }
    }

    Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could make your ListRequest object contain a list of email addresses. Then your hidden field would contain that list.

```
public class ListRequest
{
    public List<string> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
    public string FolderAccess { get; set; }
}
```

Then you'd have to change your onlcick to loop over the values in the hd1 variable.

```
if (check.Checked == true)
{
    foreach(string email in (List<string>hd1.Value))
    {
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage objEmail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        objEmail.From = new MailAddress("caio.jesus@br.com", "XXX");
        objEmail.To.Add(email);
        objEmail.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;
        objEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        objEmail.Subject = "System NDRSecurity - Novas Requisições.";
        objEmail.Body = "TEST";
        objEmail.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        objEmail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        SmtpClient objSmtp = new SmtpClient("XXX");
        objSmtp.EnableSsl = true;
        objSmtp.Port = 25;
        objSmtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("caio.jesus@br.com", "XXX");
        objSmtp.Send(objEmail);
    }
}
```

Comment: but this way I would not be showing duplicate rows in my Folder Access page? Or if I use List to email, it's continues show one row to Folder Access? My preoccupation is do not show more than one row to each "Folder Access".

Comment: The way I suggested would still only show a single row per folder.

Comment: One problem. Show one error to use ToList(). I'm using System.Collections.Generic. and System.Linq. In listRequest.Email = reader["Email"].ToList();

Comment: Yes. You will have to change the code you use to retrieve the data as well.

Comment: What I need change in my code to use ToList()? I'm using System.Collections.Generic. and System.Linq but don't resolves.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to what John Kraft suggested, if you still want to keep the `String` instead of List, is you can use a CSV of email addresses.

```
String s = "email1@email.com, email2@email.com, email3@email.com";
```

And then use Regex to split (this takes care of extra spaces):

```
foreach(string email in Regex.Split(s, @"\s*[,;]\s*"))
{ ... }
```

Comment: I was with you on this one until you got to regex. ;)  Email addresses cannot contain commas, afaik, so why not just use a string.Split?

Comment: @JohnKraft I did mention why. Some time users inputs spaces after commas (at least my users do).